# How to run Junit to test jar that does not contain the test?

Tags: java, junit

we are installing RPM to a new system and want to run all the Junit tests associated with the source code to verify that toe code works on the new system; no missing libararies or the like on the new system.  The problem is that the RPM, and thus the jar it 'installs', will not have the Junit tests compiled into it.  We have access to the original source, and thus the RPM's, seperately; but we want to test the RPM as it will ultimately be released (ie the one without unit tests).

What I would like to do is install the RPM with the jar file containing all the main code.  Then build a second jar containing just the Junit tests and then run the jobRunner class passing in both the main code jar and the Junit jar; so that ideally the Junit tests will run against the jar provided by our RPM.  I'm not certain how to do this though.  Can anyone tell me the process for creating a 'just junit' jar file from source?

Comment: Well how are you building in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create it like any other jar. You compile your code and compress it into a jar. Be sure that it only contains the test files and not the implementation. You then need to copy the jar of tests and JUnit jar (the actual JUnit framework) onto the target machine. Finally, run the JUnit tests from the command line with a class path that contains the JUnit jar, your tests jar, your application jar, and any other jars that your tests or your application need to run.